# Adding UITableView to existing UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` which open up a Camera, after doing the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` a `UITableView` shall be shown.

Somehow the tableView delegation code is not triggered. A tableView is shown on my iPhone but with empty rows. Seems that just the IB Stuff is displayed without the code. But I cannot figure out what I missed.

How do I get the `UITableView` working?

#### MainStoryboard.storyboard

```
Camera View Controller Scene
----------------------------
  Camera View Controller
    View
      Image View // hooked up with .h
      Table View  // hooked up with .h
        Table View Cell - clocation
```

#### CameraViewController.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CameraViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView; // hooked up with IB UIImageView
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *locations;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;  // hooked up with IB UITableView

@end
```

#### CameraViewController.m (Updated 20130725 with working solution)

```c
#import "CameraViewController.h"

@interface CameraViewController ()

@end

@implementation CameraViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // self.locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
    // is filled with content when photo is taken. Means has content when tableview shall be shown. 
    self.locations = @[ @"foo", @"bar" ]; // dummy setup for this thread

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            // select Photo
    } else {
        [self takePhoto];
    }

    [self initTableView];

} 

// [...] Camera Stuff


#pragma mark - table view things

-(void)initTableView {
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.delegate = self;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.locations.count;  // a breakpoint is configured but never get hit...
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"clocation";

    // Not working in this case: 
    // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // You have to use this one: 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Empty Cell %d", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: did u set the current view controller as a delegate to the table view ?

Comment: do you mean `tableView.delegate = self;`. I tried this in `initWithNibName:bundle:`, but it had no effect. I tried it like in [NSElvis Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11451564/1933185)

Comment: i assume you are loading it from a xib, so place it also in initWithCoder and make sure either initWithNibName:bundle or initWithCoder is called by placing a book mark or nslog.

Comment: its loaded from a scene in of the `MainStoryboard.storyboard`

Comment: Are you calling [tableView reloadData] when the UIImagePicker returns?

Comment: Could you show the code of imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: ?

Comment: did you check if your initWithNibName:bundle function was called

Comment: @EricGenet updated code. (at)codesburner will check.

Comment: @codesburner `initWithNibName:bundle` is not executed. I put the code into `viewDidLoad` and it seems to be executed. Currently with errors. I will investigate

Comment: are u updating self.locations with location from the new image picked in imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: if not your [self.locations count] will stay 0

Comment: Where do you update the NSMutableArray locations?

Comment: Works now. Was a combination of `_tableView.delegate = self;` and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` Thanks in advance. Will update the code in some minutes.